# Why is my HP Firefly firmware update not installing?

Tags: firmware

Edit: I am running Ubuntu 22.10, fully updated.
The Ubuntu Software App and the Update manager both indicate that there is a firmware update, but once the firmware downloads and decompresses but then I get the following error from both the command line and update utility "no HWIDs matched 09cbbed7-aafc-5da4-b4e9-ed1f69c914fb" Is this simply saying there is no update for this device or is there some issue preventing it from being installed?

```
~ $ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
T76 Ver. 01.08.00

~ $ fwupdmgr update
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • MZVLQ512HBLU-00BH1
 • Thunderbolt Dock G2
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • USB Audio 2.0
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Prometheus
 • Prometheus IOTA Config
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Upgrade System Firmware from 0x01080000 to 0x010b0000?                       ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Fixes and enhancements in System firmware 1.11.0.0:                          ║
║                                                                              ║
║ • Update BIOS to 01.11.00. Refer to hp.com for more details.                 ║
║                                                                              ║
║ HP ZBook Firefly 15.6 inch G8 Mobile Workstation PC must remain plugged      ║
║ into a power source for the duration of the update to avoid damage.          ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Perform operation? [Y|n]: 
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
no HWIDs matched 09cbbed7-aafc-5da4-b4e9-ed1f69c914fb
```

Comment: I get exactly the same error (including the same number "09cbbed7-....") on my Firefly, running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: cross-posted in HP community forum: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Update-to-firmware-0x010b0000-fails-on-Firefly-Ubuntu-20-04/m-p/8551355/highlight/true#M637296

Comment: I get the same on an HP Elitebook running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday the update completed successfully, and when I rebooted the BIOS updated itself. So at least in 22.10 this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the way to update hp firmware on a laptop is as follows:

1. Make sure your laptop has a wired internet connection and power supply.
2. Bring up a specific hp menu on startup.  I found instructions telling me to do so by pressing `ESC` and then `F10` on startup.  I instead needed to wait for the GRUB menu to load, and choose `UEFI Settings`.  On choosing this menu entry, my laptop restarted and displayed a hp menu I'd never seen before.
3. Choose `Update System Bios` in this menu.
4. Choose `Check HP.com for BIOS-Updates`.

From here on, the system should guide you with self-explanatory instructions.  The whole process will take 10–15 minutes including several automatic restarts.  The system is also supposed to tell you at the end whether the update was succesful or not.  My system did not tell me, but I have the impression that the update indeed was successful. Nothing seems to been broken in the process (though the problems that initially led me to try a firmware update also persist).

[This short guide is based on instructions circled internally within my company.  A link to official instructions from hp would be very much appreciated.]